# Maximizing the current window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, maximize-window

Is there a way I can maximize a currently minimized window from Javascript?  Here's my situation:

I have a series of links that all target the same external window (e.g. "MyNewWindow").  When I click a link, a new window pops up.  If I click another link, the page pops up in the same window as expected.  If I minimize the "MyNewWindow" popup, I'd like to be able to click another link and have that window maximize.

My approach was to put something on the onLoad part of the body so that when the page is refreshed it will automatically "maximize" if it is minimized.  Note: Using window.MoveTo() and window.resizeTo() doesnt seem to do the trick (the window stays minimized).

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't resize my windows. I use a tabbed browser and such behaviour screws with everything else, too.

Comment: This sounds really annoying: *when the page is refreshed it will automatically "maximize" if it is minimized*

Comment: This sounds like a very good reason *not* to have a load of links target an external window. It's not 1998 any more.

Answer (score 13):

For all of you know-it-alls, there are perfectly good reasons to want to know how to do this. Here's the reason I needed this:

- I'm deploying SCORM modules to a variety of Learning Management Systems (LMSs)
- One LMS that a client is using launches the module in a small (600x400) window, with the user controls to maximize or resize said window DISABLED
- The client doesn't know how to change this launch behavior

My only option is to try to maximize via javascript, because the idiots who made the LMS took away the user's ability to manage their own windows.

```
window.moveTo(0, 0);
window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

This may not work in IE depending on the security zone your page is falling under, and it may not work in Chrome at all. But for a corporate environment in an intranet, it has a good chance of working.

Comment: It might be better to use "window.moveTo(screen.availLeft, screen.availTop);" if you can. 0,0 would automatically move it to the primary window also.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this**, you are not allowed to do this by most modern browsers for a reason.

In a tabbed environment you're not messing with only the window you may have created, but **all** of my tabs, that's unacceptable.  It's the user's computer, user's browser, it's the user who *chose* to go to your site...let them size the window the way they want it, doing anything else breaks their experience...and their trust in your site.

The behavior you're looking to emulate is what your run-of-the-mill malware does...re-think your approach, *please*.  For example **focusing** that window is appropriate for what you want, let the default behavior of the browser take over from there, like this:

```
var thatWindow = window.open(url, "linkWindow");
thatWindow.focus();
```

Comment: Like @jrb said--the developer could have a perfectly good reason for doing this. It could be an internal application.

Answer (score -1):

try to use window.open(url,fullscreen=yes);
if you out fullscreen=yes than while clinking on link automatically

Comment: if you use fullscreen=yes than while clicking on link automatically maximize window open in maximize sie

Comment: Does not work (IE, Firefox, Chrome). Also: 2nd parameter of `window.open()` is window name, so you're setting the name to "fullscreen=yes". Window features should be the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I'm also assuming you meant window.open(url, "", "fullscreen=yes")
which doesn't work for me (Chrome)